# Pivoting data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am quite new to D3 and still learning.
I have data coming in the following layout

```
date,A=quantity,A=order,B=quantity,B=order,C=quantity,C=order
2016-11-01,60,2,51,4,41,1
2016-12-01,73,2,58,4,41,1
```

and would like to convert to

```
date,category,quantity,order
2016-11-01,A,60,2
2016-11-01,B,51,4
2016-11-01,C,41,1
2016-11-01,A,73,2
2016-11-01,B,58,4
2016-11-01,C,41,1
```

how can I do this using D3.js?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use a row conversion function while parsing your CSV, because you want an array with more objects than the parsed array (in other words, you want the CSV equivalent with more rows).

But you can easily get all the categories...

```
const categories = data.columns.reduce((a, c) => (c.includes("=") ? a.add(c.split("=")[0]) : null, a), new Set());
```

... and then creating your customised data array:

```
const newData = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  categories.forEach(cat => a.push({
    date: c.date,
    category: cat,
    quantity: c[`${cat}=quantity`],
    order: c[`${cat}=order`]
  }));
  return a;
}, []);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const csv = `date,A=quantity,A=order,B=quantity,B=order,C=quantity,C=order
2016-11-01,60,2,51,4,41,1
2016-12-01,73,2,58,4,41,1`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

const categories = data.columns.reduce((a, c) => (c.includes("=") ? a.add(c.split("=")[0]) : null, a), new Set());

const newData = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  categories.forEach(cat => a.push({
    date: c.date,
    category: cat,
    quantity: c[`${cat}=quantity`],
    order: c[`${cat}=order`]
  }));
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```